# serialization of class when extended by 1000 subclasses

Tags: java, serialization

When a class [say A] is serialized all the subclasses which extends A will be serialized. Suppose in case of a scenario when the class A is extended by 2000 classes do the serialized object consists of all the subclass objects. By overriding the "private void writeObject" from subclass are we completely eliminating the parent object from getting serialized. Please confirm.

Thanks and Regards,
Subbu

Comment: What happened when you tried this?  What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Why do you want to know this - please don't tell me you have a class hierarchy which is 1000 or 2000 levels deep?!

Comment: 1000 subclasses, please tell me it's an exaggerated example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When a class [say A] is serialized all the subclasses which extends A
>   will be serialized

No, the class `A` and its ***instance variables*** will be serialized, as long as the general contract of serialization is maintained.

> Suppose in case of a scenario when the class A is extended by 2000
>   classes do the serialized object consists of all the subclass objects.

The serialized representation of a class *does* [contain information about its supertypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html). But not of its subclasses.

> By overriding the "private void writeObject" from subclass are we
>   completely eliminating the parent object from getting serialized.
>   Please confirm.

No, overriding `private void writeObject` does not prevent the parent object from being serialized. Reference the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

> The writeObject method is responsible for writing the state of the
>   object for its particular class so that the corresponding readObject
>   method can restore it. The method does not need to concern itself with
>   the state belonging to the object's superclasses or subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

> When a class [say A] is serialized all the subclasses which extends A will be serialized.

Nonsense. However if a class A is *Serializable* all its derived classes will be *Serializable.*

> Suppose in case of a scenario when the class A is extended by 2000 classes do the serialized object consists of all the subclass objects.

More nonsense. However the result of any serialization consists of data for the serialized class and for all its serializable *base* classes.

> By overriding the "private void writeObject" from subclass are we completely eliminating the parent object from getting serialized.

No.

Have you read the Object Serialization Specification? It's all in there.